# Using ssh sed and regex

Tags: regex, ssh

I would replace a string in a line with SSH and regex

For example in a file config.php I would replace TO_REPLACE with OK_REPLACED :

```
define('NAME', 'TO_REPLACE');
```

I tried this command :

```
sed -i 's/^define('NAME', '\(.*?\)'/OK_REPLACED/g' config.php;
```

but it didn't work any help please?

Comment: Have a look at your quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your sed command like below,

```
sed -i "s/^\(define('NAME', *'\)[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g" config.php
```

Example:

```
$ echo "define('NAME', 'TO_REPLACE');" | sed "s/^\(define('NAME', *'\)[^']*'/\1OK_REPLACED'/g"
define('NAME', 'OK_REPLACED');
```

Comment: Hello Avinash thank you
It worked but it modified so many other lines like 'define('ADDRESS', 'TO_REPLACE');'

Comment: Thanks a lot 
Worked like a charm

Comment: Avinash what if I would replace TO_REPLACE in this string : home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo

Comment: try this `echo "home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo" | sed 's/^\(home\/\)[^\/]*\(.*\)/\1OK_REPLACED\2/g'`

Comment: THank you but :
How to add /dmwebolabo at the end because there is other similar lines that bigin with home/
(working with putty)

Comment: you mean this `echo "home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo" | sed 's/^\(home\/\)[^\/]*\/dmwebolabo/\1OK_REPLACED\/dmwebolabo/g'` ?

Comment: Didn't work 
With Putty I just need to replace TO_REPLACE and keep all the other line as it is please thank you home/TO_REPLACE/dmwebolabo

Comment: yep, the above command would replace the text `TO_REPLACE` on that particular line only.

Comment: It didn't nothing to the file 
I see twice demwebolabo it's normal?

Comment: did you add `-i` parameter?

Comment: yes `sed -i 's/^\(home\/\)[^\/]*\/dmwebolabo/\1OK_REPLACED\/dmwebolabo/g'`

Comment: Avinash could you help please :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your sed line.

1) You messed up with the quotes. if you want to avoid escaping, you should wrap one kind with another. like `" ...' ...' ...' "` or `'...."...."..."...'`

2) sed regex default is BRE, with `-r` (gnu sed) it supports ERE, but none of them supports `non-greedy`, so your `.*?` won't work with sed.

This line should go with your need:

```
sed -i "s/^\(define('NAME', '\)[^']*/\1OK_REPLACED/" config.php
```

Comment: It's OK now thank you very much I just removed the anchor because it was with other lines